# How to make Gradle recognize JetBrains annotations

Tags: gradle, jetbrains-ide

I use @NotNull annotation in my project and when I refresh the project, Gradle has a problem:

`Could not find org.jetbrains:annotations:21.0.0.`

How can Gradle recognize the annotation?

Comment: You probably need to add a repository declaration. How does you `build.gradle` look like?